# Not able to Fetch data from firebase realtime database in a fragment and getting no error messages

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am new in respect to fetching data from Firebase Realtime Database in an Android app. Till now I have just found the code on the internet and changed it as per my requirement. I have created my realtime database in Firebase and also connected the same to my android app. So, In my android application I have a navigation view which navigates to 4 different Fragments inside mainActivity.kt file. I have created 2 fragments in java, hope that is not a issue here?

So, item fragment here is fetching the data from firebase and note fragment here is sending notes to firebase realtime database. I am using a recycler view inside item fragment. I get no error messages but I am unable to view the data in the item fragment and when I try to send notes inside note fragment the app crashes. I am not able to figure out the reason for this. Can anyone help?

Here is my code for item fragment:

```
package com.MechaProjectS6.whatisinmyfridge.fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.MechaProjectS6.whatisinmyfridge.R;
import com.MechaProjectS6.whatisinmyfridge.adapter.myadapter;
import com.MechaProjectS6.whatisinmyfridge.model.model;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class ItemFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    myadapter adapter;


    public ItemFragment() {

    }

    public static ItemFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        ItemFragment fragment = new ItemFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item, container, false);

        recyclerView = (view.findViewById(R.id.recycler));
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<model> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<model>()
                        .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("items"), model.class)
                        .build();

        adapter = new myadapter(options);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

Here is the model class

```
package com.MechaProjectS6.whatisinmyfridge.model;

public class model {

    String Item, TimeStamp, Weight;

    public model() {
    }

    public model(String item, String timeStamp, String weight) {
        Item = item;
        TimeStamp = timeStamp;
        Weight = weight;
    }

    public String getItem() {
        return Item;
    }

    public void setItem(String item) {
        Item = item;
    }

    public String getTimeStamp() {
        return TimeStamp;
    }

    public void setTimeStamp(String timeStamp) {
        TimeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    public String getWeight() {
        return Weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(String weight) {
        Weight = weight;
    }
}
```

Here is the adapter file

```
package com.MechaProjectS6.whatisinmyfridge.adapter;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.MechaProjectS6.whatisinmyfridge.R;
import com.MechaProjectS6.whatisinmyfridge.model.model;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;

public class myadapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<model, myadapter.myViewHolder> {


    public myadapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<model> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull model model) {
        holder.txtTimeStamp.setText(model.getTimeStamp());
        holder.txtItemName.setText(model.getItem());
        holder.txtItemWeight.setText(model.getWeight());

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recycler_dashboard_single_row, parent, false);

        return new myViewHolder(view);

    }

    public class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView txtTimeStamp, txtItemName, txtItemWeight;

        public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txtTimeStamp = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTimeStamp);
            txtItemName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtItemName);
            txtItemWeight = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtItemWeight);



        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Note Fragment

```
package com.MechaProjectS6.whatisinmyfridge.fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.MechaProjectS6.whatisinmyfridge.R;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class NoteFragment extends Fragment {

    EditText e1;
    Button b1;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public NoteFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static NoteFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        NoteFragment fragment = new NoteFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes, container, false);

        e1 = view.findViewById(R.id.add_notes);
        b1 = view.findViewById(R.id.button);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String fruitName = e1.getText().toString().trim();
                if (!fruitName.isEmpty()) {
                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

                    int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                    int minutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                    String time = hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;


                    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    String date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;

                    String DateTimes = "Date: " + date + " Time " + time;
                    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy:HH:mm:ss");
                    Date dateobj = new Date();
                    String d = df.format(dateobj);

                    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notes");
                    databaseReference.child("DateTime:" + d).setValue(fruitName);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Saved Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e1.setText("");
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter Fruit name and Weight", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Here I am also adding the xml files
For item Fragment :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragment.ItemFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtItemName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text = "@string/items_in_fridge" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below = "@+id/txtItemName"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Single Row for Recycler view :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3.3">
    
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/black">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTimeStamp"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Time Stamp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtItemName"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtTimeStamp"
            android:text="List Item"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtItemWeight"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtItemName"
            android:text="200g"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    
        </RelativeLayout>
    
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

For notes Fragment :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragment.NoteFragment">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editAddNotes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:hint="Add Notes"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editAddNotes"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="Save"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[Here is a screenshot of database:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igdHh.png)

Comment: The problem is the naming of your fields in the database, which are different from the ones you have in your class. Please check the duplicate to see how you can solve this.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem here, I had set read and write to false in firebase, after I changed it to true it worked as expected, but when I try to send notes to the firebase the app crashes and data is also not sent